# What does it mean, "teeth, tits and tan"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Fletcher says to Ray about Michael Pearson:

> Fletcher: He was powerful and ruthless, cunning and quick, charismatic
>   and smart, but...he had to do some naughty things to get where he got,
>   to establish his position, to show he wasn't just **teeth, tits and tan**.

What does it mean, "teeth, tits and tan"?

I find this line in The Gentlemen 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teeth, tits (breasts, only for females, usually) and tan are all superficial attributes that, e.g. in Hollwood actors, participants in reality TV shows, and possibly politicians, can be made fashionably acceptable using dental work, cosmetic surgery, and UV lamps, respectively. To be known for only those things implies a lack of depth or originality and an artificial surface-based nature.